# Android Splunk SDK 5.2.5 gradle is failing to sync

Tags: android, gradle, splunk, splunk-sdk

I am trying to add Splunk sdk and gradle is failing to sync with `Cause: javacTask` I will add the stacktrace.

I have `mint-android-repo-5.2.5.zip` folder under app folder (so it is app > mint-plugin-repo-5.2.5)

I am using Android studio 3.4, and below is my gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'com.splunk.mint.gradle.android.plugin'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: "kotlin-kapt"

buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url uri('mint-plugin-repo-5.2.5')
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.splunk:mint-gradle-android-plugin:5.2.5'
    }
}

repositories {
    maven {
        url uri('mint-plugin-repo-5.2.5')
    }
}

apply from: 'jacoco.gradle'
```

stack trace

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: javacTask
    at com.splunk.mint.gradle.android.plugin.utils.VariantUtilsKt.getJavaTask(VariantUtils.kt:13)
    at com.splunk.mint.gradle.android.plugin.api.AspectJTransform.setupVariant(AspectJTransform.kt:81)
    at com.splunk.mint.gradle.android.plugin.api.AspectJTransform$prepareProject$1.execute(AspectJTransform.kt:57)
    at com.splunk.mint.gradle.android.plugin.api.AspectJTransform$prepareProject$1.execute(AspectJTransform.kt:43)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction$1$1.run(DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator.java:150)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.reapply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:58)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction$1.run(DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator.java:147)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:402)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:394)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:92)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator$BuildOperationEmittingAction.execute(DefaultListenerBuildOperationDecorator.java:144)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$ActionInvocationHandler.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:80)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:230)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:149)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:58)
    ... 126 more
```

Comment: I don't understand why, but I added the multidex, and disabled the apply plugin line, and it built and worked

Comment: Disabling the plugin also worked for me ... Here is another SO thread, which may be helpful to others: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55938833/how-do-i-install-the-splunk-mint-gradle-plugin